# An endomorphism of a tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra with basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, and let $B$ be any $k$-algebra. I am dealing with an endomorphism $f:A\otimes_k B \to A\otimes_k B$.

1. What difference is there between considering $f$ as a homomorphism of $k$-algebras or $B$-algebras?
2. Does $f$ induce a canonical map $A\to A$ of $k$-algebras? I tried the following: take $a=\sum \lambda_ie_i$ and $b\in B$, then $$f(a\otimes b)=\sum \lambda_i f(e_i\otimes b).$$ Assuming $f$ to be a $B$-algebra homomorphism we can further write $e_i\otimes b=b(e_i\otimes 1)$ so that $f(a\otimes b)=\sum \lambda_i b f(e_i\otimes 1)$ (not so sure about that). I was hoping for $f(e_i\otimes 1)$ to land in $A$ so that I may define $A\to A$ as $e_i\mapsto f(e_i\otimes 1)$.
3. Can one expect the basis elements $e_i$ to be pairwise orthogonal? or to be idempotent?

Answer (score 1):

1. $f$ a homomorphism of $k$-algebras means that it is a ring homomorphism which is also $k$-linear, while $f$ a homomorphism of $B$-algebras means it is a ring homomorphism which is also $B$-linear. It's possible that a $k$-linear homomorphism may not be $B$-linear depending on the action - for instance, if $A=k$ and $B=k[t]$, the $k$-linear homomorphism defined by sending $t\mapsto t+1$ is not $B$-linear.
2. Yes, the identity map is something you can always pick as an automorphism.
3. No, you can't guarantee either. For instance, if $A$ is a nontrivial field extension of $k$, then neither of those properties can hold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For (2), I think I didn't do a good job explaining myself, so I edited that part of the question.